# Using default values when initializing a superclass from a subclass in Python

Tags: python

Why doesn't Python use the default argument values when initializing a superclass?

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, list=[]):
        self.list = list

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, item):
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.list.append(item)

x = Sub(1)
y = Sub(2)

print x.list   # prints [1, 2]
print y.list   # prints [1, 2]
```

In this case, it seems that there is only one 'list' variable that's shared between the two instances of Sub.  I can solve the issue by explicitly passing the value of 'list', i.e.:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, list=[]):
        self.list = list

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, item):
        Base.__init__(self, list=[])
        self.list.append(item)

x = Sub(1)
y = Sub(2)

print x.list   # prints [1]
print y.list   # prints [2]
```

Is there a way to avoid passing the argument explicitly in such cases?  In my actual application, I have a lot of default values in my superclasses and it causes a lot of code duplication to pass them all again every time I initialize a subclass.

Comment: This is a slight variation of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) - If you address the issues there, your problem will vanish...

Comment: Tl;dr: don't use mutable default arguments (or names that shadow Python built-ins!); use `lst=None`

Answer (score 0):

As Jon pointed out, you are mutating your default argument every time. If you want an empty list (but not the same one) to be the default, do this (noting how you set the new list to a full slice of the parameter):

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, list=None):
        self.list = [] if list == None else list

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, item):
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.list.append(item)

x = Sub(1)
y = Sub(2)

print x.list   # prints [1, 2]
print y.list   # prints [1, 2]
```

Incidentally, you should probably avoid naming any variables *list* since that is the name of the *list* type.

Comment: This, however, is both wasteful and not always what one wants (`Base(please_mutate_this_list)`).

Comment: This is not good advice; if you want to use a mutable default argument, use `default=None` then `if default is None: default = []`

Comment: You're probably right; I'll change it. (But it's a duplicate anyway)